# Can Spring security be made to work for JSF navigations?

Tags: jsf, spring-security

My problem is very similar to this existing SO post:
[JSF - Spring Security Integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177104/jsf-spring-security-integration-issue)

Ravi's response regarding disabling once-per-request and specifying FORWARD to "get it to work" is echo'd other places on the web, namely:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/61490/oa/Spring-security-intercept-url
and long ago:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?11025-lt-jsp-forward-gt-bypasses-Acegi

However, I'm just not able to get this to work.  I've done both the items Ravi's response suggests:

1) put once-per-request in spring's config:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="false">
   <intercept-url pattern="/partners/**" access="ROLE_PARTNER" />
.
.
.
</http>
```

2) include FORWARD:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my case, I've got a command link into the partners section of my application that works (but shouldn't). It *is* true that every link after this first one and any searches posted do NOT work. But the initial navigation into /parterns/** does work, and I don't think it should.

```
<p:menuitem>
  <h:commandLink ajax="false" action="/partners/search/partnerSearch"
                 styleClass="ui-menuitem-link
                 ui-corner-all">
                 <h:outputText value="Partners"/>
  </h:commandLink>
</p:menuitem>
```

I'm assuming this means that JSF doesn't actually use a request dispatcher forward to "forward" to the navigation outcome (and thus, Spring never gets a chance to re-evaluate the security).  I've tried placing breakpoints and looking for myself, but it's slightly beyond my understanding what I'm seeing.

I'm aware that I can use a redirect (but like the first SO post I linked to, don't want to do this). I'm also aware that I can put `<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_PARTNER">` around the menu item to prevent the click in the first place.

I'm actually just curious as to why this doesn't work at all, when a few sources seem to indicate it should.

My experience of it not working, is echo'd at least one other place:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82900-FilterSecurityInterceptor-not-being-called-for-a-JSF-forward

My stuff is:

```
<spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jsf.version>2.1.23</jsf.version> (mojarra)
<primeFaces.version>3.5.9</primeFaces.version>
```

Comment: Hey, one more reason why navigation using POST is a bad practice.

Comment: fair enough, but any ideas as to why it won't work as desired?

Comment: Simply because the Spring Security filter isn't hit.